# for-loop not working: trying to turn a ls into an array

Tags: bash, shell, for-loop

I'm receiving a snytax error when I run the following code:

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in (`ls *.nexus`);

do
   awk 'NR >5' /path/to/nexus_files/$i | tr -d "'" | tr " " "\n" | sed 's/uce/>uce/g' > /path/to/fasta_files/${i}.fasta

done
```

error:

```
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `(
```

when I remove parentheses:

```
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token 'awk'
```

Answer (score 3):

In your simple example, you can do w/o the `ls` command

```
for i in *.nexus ; do
    awk ...
done
```

Comment: Then it seems to me that you have a problem with your pipeline rather than a problem with the for loop... Imho you should ask another question, specifying the format of the data, the expected output and what you get instead.

Comment: Probably you should [`use more quotes`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Practices#Quoting)... `/path/to/nexus_files/$i` -> `/path/to/nexus_files/"$i"` ?

Comment: @anishsane You're right: "Too much quotes are almost enough".